# Finding ${\partial \over \partial x}(zyx^2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, soft-question, partial-derivative, education

> Find ${\partial \over \partial x}(zyx^2)$

So I was discussing with one of my students that you can keep track of partial derivatives with the following:

$$\begin{align} {\partial \over \partial x} (zyx^2) &= zy{\partial \over \partial x}(x^2) \tag{$zy$ is constant} \\ &=2xyz\end{align}$$

My colleague told me that teaching students this way is bad because it is abuse of notation.

I don't fully understand why this might be abuse of notation exactly. Is there something mathematically incorrect that could come up with using such a method to explain the partial derivative?

Comment: I don't see the abuse of notation here. The only thing that's really tricky is whether $z$ or $y$ might be "hidden" functions of $x$ (i.e. they actually depend on $x$ but we write them as $z$ and $y$ instead of $z(x)$ and $y(x)$). But that's always tricky to keep track of regardless of how you do the notation.

Comment: Which is dependent variable?

Comment: Your colleague is wrong. This is pretty standard. y and z aren't important in the partial derivative and can be moved out of it. Unless, of course, y and z is dependent on x, but that's an unusual case.

Answer (score 1):

If $y$ and $z$ are each independent of $x$, then it is not an abuse of notation and your colleague is wrong.

If either of $y$ or $z$ depend on $x$, then your answer is wrong.